# LaTeX PDF file appears then disappears

Tags: pdf, texmaker

I've been using LaTex with the texmaker as an editor for a while, but recently I've never been able to view the PDF I create because of a "file not found" error. If I look at the folder the tex file is in, when I click "PDFLaTeX" to compile the tex file a PDF momentarily appears and disappears. I have no idea how it's happening, and can't view any of my LaTeX produced documents as a result.

Comment: There could be some settings in TeXmaker that is making things disappear. Could you supply some of the build information?

Comment: sounds to me like you have a LaTeX error and TeXMaker deletes the not succesfully build pdf-file. Can you provide the error and the content of the .log-file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.     A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".